# Running command with Google Authentication via Google Colab

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, curl, google-oauth, google-colaboratory

Let's take this Google Colab curl command as an example:

```
!curl -X POST \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
  --data '{"nlpService": "projects/PROJECTNAME/locations/us-central1/services/nlp", "documentContent": '"'$(cat /content/drive/MyDrive/myfile.txt)'"' }' "https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECTNAME/locations/us-central1/services/nlp:analyzeEntities"
```

According to https://curlconverter.com/, this will give me the following code, which doesn't work when I run it:

```
import subprocess
import requests

command1 = subprocess.run('cat /content/drive/MyDrive/myfile.txt', shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout
command2 = subprocess.run('gcloud auth application-default print-access-token', shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + command2,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
}

data = '{"nlpService": "projects/PROJECTNAME/locations/us-central1/services/nlp", "documentContent": \'' + command1 + "' }"

response = requests.post(
    'https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECTNAME/locations/us-central1/services/nlp:analyzeEntities',
    headers=headers,
    data=data,
)
```

I've seen other Google Authentication methods via Python, but it doesn't do the job. I've even substituted the data portion of the command with the text string from the Drive, but I was still unable to get past the authorization portion of the code, which is `-H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)"`. Any guidance is appreciated to switching from calling into `/bin/sh` using curl into using Python instead.

The error that I've received from running the Python command above is

```
ValueError: Invalid header value b'Bearer <<result of command2, which is the access token>>
```

I've added the following code before the variable `command1`, but it seems that I'm still unable to authenticate:

```
!gcloud auth application-default login --scopes=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/content/.config/application_default_credentials.json"
```

Comment: 1) What does not work? Usually, the error message and stack trace are helpful. 2) There are two types of identities in Google Cloud. Google Accounts (users) and Google Cloud service accounts. Which type did you configure for the CLI `gcloud`? Most likely Google Healthcare requires an access token generated from a user identity and not a service account. Run this command and login with a user identity with permissions (scopes) to Healthcare: `gcloud auth application-default login --scopes=<REQUIRED SCOPES>` Link: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login

Comment: I go by this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/healthcare-api/docs/concepts/nlp, which gives me a token when I run```gcloud auth application-default print-access-token``` . If I go by ```gcloud auth application-default login --scopes=<REQUIRED SCOPES>```, it's going to come up empty when I input the required scopes. The error that I've received is ```ValueError: Invalid header value b'Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN VALUE from running the subprocess command>```

Comment: If you want a valid token from `print-access-token` you must first authenticate using the command in my comment.

Comment: I see, maybe I'm a bit slow in understanding. Do I run the command from your comment first with a subprocess, store that into a variable, set the os envionment to the JSON produced with ```os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/content/.config/application_default_credentials.json"```, and then obtain the token with the command ```gcloud auth application-default print-access-token```? I think I got a 401 response error with that also. Not sure if there's something wrong with my code or not. I've edited my answer to reflect on what I've tried.

Comment: You added two problems. 1) The Health API is not part of Google Cloud, so specifying a cloud based scope is not useful. You must specify a Health scope. 2) This line is not useful, remove it: `os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = ...` That line is only used if you are specifying a service account JSON file that you downloaded.